# Dynamic access to Mongodb field

Tags: mongodb

The problem is how to access to fiels value in .find() request.

I tried to access with this.cteatedAt, but it not working.

```
const bestJobs = await Job.find({
  $and: [
    {category: 'Programming'},
    {status: 'best'},
    {8 : {$lte: moment().utc().diff(this.cteatedAt, 'minutes')}}
  ]
}).sort({createdAt: -1});
```

Have no results.

My collection:

#### bestJobs

```
{
    "_id": "5d455d85232b540b1c05dcaf",
    "jobTitle": "new",
    "category": "Programming",
    "jobType": "Full-Time",
    "tags": "Гейм-дизайн, левел-дизайн",
    "headOffice": "Moscow",
    "region": "Moscow",
    "applyLink": "sdfsdfds",
    "jobDescription": "dsffdsfdsfsd",
    "name": "ARKPlay",
    "companyStatement": "вааццауцуа",
    "logo": "logo\9-08-03T10-10-13.351Z6mnO8wnjYwQ.jpg",
    "websiteURL": "выаоывадоывадыавод",
    "email": "arkhannanov@gmail.com",
    "aboutCompany": "wfwfewfejl",
    "status": "best",
    "payment": false,
    "createdAt": "2019-08-03T10:10:13.389Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-08-03T10:10:13.389Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention that, but I assumed you are trying to find jobs which where created 8 minutes ago or later. If `createdAt` type is **Date** you can do it using the following code:

```
const _8minutesAgo = moment().utc().subtract(8, 'minutes').toDate()
const bestJobs = await Job.find({
  category: 'Programming',
  status: 'best',
  createdAt : {$gt: _8minutesAgo}
}).sort({createdAt: -1})
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, Cider! But _8minutesAgo showing as unresolved varible or type  _8minutesAgo. Not working.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Trying again

Comment: I agree, logic is ok. But comparision is not working. Type of cteatedAt fiels is Date.

Comment: Can you please provide the collection and the expected output?

Comment: Can not add code, do not know how. Here is screenshot from database Robo 3T http://prntscr.com/ontds6

Comment: `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields type is string. Can you cast them to Date before insertion?

Comment: My bad. I edited my answer and changed the name of `cteatedAt` to `createdAt`. Does it solves your problem?

Comment: Perfect, now working. Sorry for inattention. What now I have to do to accept your answer so it become solved? Many Many Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)
You can tick the big V icon near my original answer.
Additional information about stackoverflow interface can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Perfect! Have a nice day!